# Is it okay to have a password in a cookie or session?

Tags: php, session, cookies, encryption, passwords

I'm making a PHP CMS and I was wondering if it was okay to have, a small password encrypted in a cookie so certain users can access the admin zone who know the password. It will be encrypted, and the encryption key will be the password itself... Is this safe or not? What are the dangers of this? Would it be better in a session?

Sorry, I don't know two much about this.

Comment: The encryption key is the password itself? So the plaintext is the same as the key? What exactly would be the point of this?

Comment: Could you explain what a password stored in a cookie or session would be used for? It sounds a bit strange to store in an extra place besides (I presume) the database. The fewer places you store security sensitive information, the better.

Comment: Hi Speedysnal6 and welcome. I've linked to something that provides an answer, even if the question is not *fully* identical. Note that this does not concern programming per se, security questions should really be asked at *http://security.stackexchange.com*, after searching if the question has not been asked before, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store password in the cookie to log in to some service, right? So, if I obtain the encrypted password (just by looking in the cookies, its not that hard), the only thing i have to do to access this account is to create cookie with this password? I would say it's not the best idea ;)

Yes - creating session id stored in cookie, that is temporary and destroyed on logout / after predefined time - is better practise.

Comment: I was thinking of a session that lasted for about 10 years so the user is always logged in :P. I'll do sessions